# Get data of p element of div element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know how can i get data of `p` element which is a children of `div` element. remember there are many `div` elements with same classes. it would be better to use events. As i am beginner I am unable to do it.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".wp-block-wish-block-01-wish-block-01-editable").find('.social-link').on('click', function(event) {
    var elementText = $(event.target).text();
    console.log(elementText);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wp-block-wish-block-01-wish-block-01-editable share-block-content">
  <p class="ab-testimonial-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque porro incidunt error nostrum, labore saepe pariatur similique officia voluptatem! Repellendus iure commodi aliquid nemo nisi rerum quasi sunt, ducimus libero!. </p>
  <div class="block-share-links">
    <strong>Share:</strong>
    <div class="share-links">
      <a class="social-link" href="#"><img src="http://localhost/cs/wp-content/plugins/wish-block/assets/021-facebook.png"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://localhost/cs/wp-content/plugins/wish-block/assets/043-twitter.png"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://localhost/cs/wp-content/plugins/wish-block/assets/049-stumbleupon.png"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are many blocks like this. What i want to do is that when user clicks the `.social-link` the text of first element `p` should be logged in console using jQuery or JavaScript.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. Remember that SO is here to help debug code, not to write it for you.

Comment: sorry forgot to share jquery code

Comment: Did you mean `$(event.target).text()` instead of `$(event.target).text`? Is that a typo?

Comment: it was a typo error, thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem. It searches for the closest parent of the clicked element which has the specified class. Then it looks for the first child element (because of the `>`) with the specified class and extracts its text.

```
$('.social-link').click(function() {
  var value = $(this).closest('.share-block-content').find('> .ab-testimonial-title').text();
  console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: Just FYI, `children('.ab-testimonial-title')` would perform better than `find('> .ab-testimonial-title')`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose all of these blocks share the class `share-block-content`. Then it would be possible to get the text of the `<p>` element like this:

```js
$(".social-link").on("click", function() {
  let text = $(this).closest(".share-block-content").find("p").text();
  console.log(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wp-block-wish-block-01-wish-block-01-editable share-block-content">
  <p class="ab-testimonial-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque porro incidunt error nostrum, labore saepe pariatur similique officia voluptatem! Repellendus iure commodi aliquid nemo nisi rerum quasi sunt, ducimus libero!. </p>
  <div class="block-share-links">
    <strong>Share:</strong>
    <div class="share-links">
      <a class="social-link" href="#"><img src="http://localhost/cs/wp-content/plugins/wish-block/assets/021-facebook.png"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://localhost/cs/wp-content/plugins/wish-block/assets/043-twitter.png"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://localhost/cs/wp-content/plugins/wish-block/assets/049-stumbleupon.png"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> What i want to do is that when user clicks the `.social-link` the text of first element `p` should be logged in console

You can do this easily by using the [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to find the closest parent element with class as `share-block-content` and then find the first `p` inside that div like:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".wp-block-wish-block-01-wish-block-01-editable").find('.social-link').on('click', function(event) {
    var elementText = $(this).closest('.share-block-content').find('p:first').text();
    console.log(elementText);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wp-block-wish-block-01-wish-block-01-editable share-block-content">
  <p class="ab-testimonial-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque porro incidunt error nostrum, labore saepe pariatur similique officia voluptatem! Repellendus iure commodi aliquid nemo nisi rerum quasi sunt, ducimus libero!. </p>
  <div class="block-share-links">
    <strong>Share:</strong>
    <div class="share-links">
      <a class="social-link" href="#"><img src="http://localhost/cs/wp-content/plugins/wish-block/assets/021-facebook.png"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://localhost/cs/wp-content/plugins/wish-block/assets/043-twitter.png"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://localhost/cs/wp-content/plugins/wish-block/assets/049-stumbleupon.png"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for help. truly love this community. thanks for help. would have accepted your answer but @ssc-hrep3 answered before. hope you wouldn't mind. again, thanks

Comment: No probs at all, as long as it helped. You can always show your appreciation to others using upvotes though ;)